# Unity shader - How to generate normal map based on texture map

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl

I'm currently stuck in a shader that i'm writing.
I'm trying to create a rain shader.
I have set up 3 particle system which simulates rain, and a
camera to look at this simulation. The camera view is what I
use as texture. In my shader I am now trying to make a normal map
from that texture map, but I don't know how to do it.

```
Shader "Unlit/Rain"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _NormalIntensity("NormalIntensity",Float) = 1
      
    }
        SubShader
        {
            
            Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
            LOD 100

            Pass
            {
                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"
                #include "Lighting.cginc"
                #include "AutoLight.cginc"

                struct VertexInput {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float4 normal : NORMAL;
                    float3 tangent : TANGENT;

                };

                struct VertexOutput {
                    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                    float2 uv1 : TEXCOORD1;
                    float4 normals : NORMAL;

                    float3 tangentSpaceLight: TANGENT;
                   
                };

                sampler2D _MainTex;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;
                half4 _Color;
                float _NormalIntensity;

                VertexOutput vert(VertexInput v) {

                    VertexOutput o;
                    o.normals = v.normal;
                    o.uv1 = v.uv;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos( v.vertex );
                   // o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX( v.uv, _MainTex ); // used for texture

                    return o;
                }



                float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR{

                    float4 col2 = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv1); 
                    return col2 * i.normals * 5;
                }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
}
```

[This is what the camera sees. I set the TargetTexture for this camera to be a texture I created.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JigEc.png)

[In my shader I then put that texture as an albedo property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6gwa.png)

So what I wanna do is now find the normal for that texture to create a bumpmap.

Comment: What do you mean, "based on" the texture map? If the texture map is a render, what does that have to do with normals?

Comment: @Ruzihm I have posted an answer below :)

Comment: Answers below should be answers to this post, next time please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70202745/edit) to include clarifying info. :)

Comment: Okay sry. I'm new to this :) Do you have an answer for the question ? :)

Comment: You could try [interpreting it as a height map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57185308/1092820) . There's not really a satisfying way to guess the shape of something based on its appearance, without anything else like a heightmap. especially in a fast way suitable for a shader. If the shader was on the particle systems themselves instead of a rendertexture, you could have the particle system create a normal map that the shader could use, since the particle system knows things like particle velocity, droplet size, etc. That would probably be easier.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? If the answer below helped, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359).

Comment: haha thank you for reminding me @Ruzihm :D The answer was very good, and it works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your "TargetTexture" is giving you back a height map. Here is a post I found about [how to turn a height map into a normal map](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/594781-hlsl-height-map-to-normal-algorithm/). I've mashed the code you had originally together with the core of that forum post and output the normals as color so you can test and see how this works:

```
Shader "Unlit/HeightToNormal"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _NormalIntensity("NormalIntensity",Float) = 1
        _HeightMapSizeX("HeightMapSizeX",Float) = 1024
        _HeightMapSizeY("HeightMapSizeY",Float) = 1024
    }
    SubShader
    {

        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "Lighting.cginc"
            #include "AutoLight.cginc"

            struct VertexInput {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 normal : NORMAL;
                float3 tangent : TANGENT;

            };

            struct VertexOutput {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv1 : TEXCOORD1;
                float4 normals : NORMAL;

                //float3 tangentSpaceLight: TANGENT;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            half4 _Color;
            float _NormalIntensity;
            float _HeightMapSizeX;
            float _HeightMapSizeY;

            VertexOutput vert(VertexInput v) {

                VertexOutput o;
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX( v.uv, _MainTex ); // used for texture
                o.uv1 = v.uv;
                o.normals = v.normal;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);

                 return o;
             }

            float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR
            {
                float me = tex2D(_MainTex,i.uv1).x;
                float n = tex2D(_MainTex,float2(i.uv1.x, i.uv1.y + 1.0 / _HeightMapSizeY)).x;
                float s = tex2D(_MainTex,float2(i.uv1.x, i.uv1.y - 1.0 / _HeightMapSizeY)).x;
                float e = tex2D(_MainTex,float2(i.uv1.x + 1.0 / _HeightMapSizeX,i.uv1.y)).x;
                float w = tex2D(_MainTex,float2(i.uv1.x - 1.0 / _HeightMapSizeX,i.uv1.y)).x;

                // defining starting normal as color has some interesting effects, generally makes this more flexible
                float3 norm = _Color;
                float3 temp = norm; //a temporary vector that is not parallel to norm
                if (norm.x == 1)
                temp.y += 0.5;
                else
                temp.x += 0.5;

                //form a basis with norm being one of the axes:
                float3 perp1 = normalize(cross(i.normals,temp));
                float3 perp2 = normalize(cross(i.normals,perp1));

                //use the basis to move the normal i its own space by the offset
                float3 normalOffset = -_NormalIntensity * (((n - me) - (s - me)) * perp1 + ((e - me) - (w - me)) * perp2);
                norm += normalOffset;
                norm = normalize(norm);

                // it's also interesting to output temp, perp1, and perp1, or combinations of the float samples.
                return float4(norm, 1);
            }
            ENDCG
         }
    }
}
```

To generate a normal map from a height map, you're trying to use the oriented rate of change in your height map to come up with a normal vector which can be represented using 3 float values (or color channels, if it's an image). You can sample the point of image you are on, and then small steps away from that point in four cardinal directions. Using the cross product to guarantee orthogonality you can define a basis. Using your oriented steps on your image, you can scale the two basis vectors and add them together to find a "normal offset", which is the 3D representation approximating the oriented change in value on your heightmap. Basically it's your normal.

You can see the effects of me playing with normal intensity [here](https://gyazo.com/69d12655d592b9112915e54c2fe891e3), and the "normal color" [here](https://gyazo.com/f6d334d7d5d2a1c9e9fdf5f2599d8659). When this looks right for your use case, you can try using normals as normals instead of colored output.

Some tweaking of values will probably still be required. Good luck!

Comment: I think this is about as good as it'll get unless asker can get the particle generator to output normal data. Great answer

Comment: Thank you so much :D I will try to implement this to see if it works :)

Comment: @NSJacob is the 'heightMapSampler' my texture that I receive from the camera? and in that case what is the 'heightMapSizeY' and 'heightMapSizeX' then ? I don´t understand the post you linked to completely also since the majority of the shader is not included there :( Can you help with this ?

Comment: Yes, in this example 'heightMapSampler' would be the texture you receive from the camera. UV's are floats from 0 to 1, so something like `IN.tex.y + 1.0/heightMapSizeY` would mean "sample a value effectively one pixel higher in the y axis given a `heightMapSizeX by heightMapSizeY` sized texture."

Comment: Tried it out in the editor, made a little shader toy to play with. It turns a heightmap image into a normal image, basically the core of the problem as I understand it.

Comment: @NSJacob1 sorry for the many questions but how can I then figure out the height x and y of my texture ? is there a specific common for this ? and thank you so much for the help btw :D

Comment: You should use the resolution of your texture.